# generalised code to connect to database engines using jdbc4?

Tags: java, jdbc, driver

I am developing an application which simulates datacubes and their operation. For this application I need to provide support for various database engines such as PostgreSQL, MySQL, etc.
I was planning on providing an interface where the user can choose the engine and specify its details.

I have been able to connect to PostgreSQL using the JDBC4 driver available. For this connection I had to compile my program code by including the .jar driver in the classpath during compilation.
But the application as a product should run on JRE and there should be no need to recompile the code. Is this possible?

The application should also be customizable to the newer versions of driver and engines available for the database. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *for this connection i had to compile my program code by including the .jar driver in the classpath during compilation.*

You should not need to do this. That's actually the whole point of JDBC. You should provide the driver class name (and the connection URL, username and/or password) as a string which can be retrieved from some external configuration (properties?) file. E.g.

```
String driverClassName = getItFromConfigurationFileSomehow();
Class.forName(driverClassName);
// ...
```

Even more, since JDBC4 the `Class#forName()` is not necessary at all. Just put the JDBC driver in the runtime classpath and let the `ServiceLoader` API do its automatic job of loading the driver.

You only need to rewrite your code to **only** use `java.sql` interfaces/classes like `java.sql.Connection` and so on instead of `org.postgresql` interfaces/classes so that you do not need the JDBC driver during compile. In other words, you should not have any single line of code which imports/references the JDBC driver specific interfaces/classes.

Comment: can that be done using java.sql alone without the use of a database engine driver? how ? please elaborate

Comment: The whole point of JDBC API is that you don't need to compile against a specific JDBC driver. You just need to put it in runtime classpath and specify the driver class name in some way or just make use of the new JDBC4 serviceloader API (so that you don't need `Class#forName()` at all). It's only your own code which is incorrectly importing/using JDBC driver specific classes. Replace all `org.postgresql` imports/references by `java.sql` ones.

Answer (score 1):

You can load the driver class via reflection as mentioned by BalusC, after that you can use DriverManager to get a connection. Then you stick to the java.sql or javax.sql interfaces and you should be good to go.

If you intend for this code to be used by any sort of web application, this approach will work, but it will have severe drawbacks. This approach interferes with application reloading, and this is a *huge* pain during development.

If you expect to use this in a web application, you should make it an option to retrieve your database connections from a data source. This way the web container is the one that actually loads the driver, and your application doesn't pay the penalty for being the one that loaded the driver class.

Your database library code just needs to use the data source API to retrieve the connection and then the java[x].sql interfaces to manipulate the database. So its only a difference in the way that a database connection is retrieved.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need more insights on DB Frameworks. Here it is a naive framework I have started some years ago...

[St-Toolkit](http://st-toolkit.sourceforge.net/)

you can take a look at it for inspiration:

[Javadoc](http://st-toolkit.sourceforge.net/software/doc/)

Comment: You can also consider looking at this OpenSource solution: Mondrian - http://mondrian.pentaho.com/ which is cross-relational-db solution for data-warehousing

Comment: the application is supposed to provide a simulation not real data warehousing complex capabilities..